# Linux - How to rename files in batch while removing pattern in filename

Tags: linux, file, sh, rename

I have hundreds of files in a directory all have the suffix "_aac" in the name.  For example: weoi32rijwef_aac.mp4

How can I rename all of these files in a batch process to remove the "_aac" from their filenames?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Much simpler way is

```
cd /to/that/directory
rename 's/_aac//' *
```

Comment: This worked great for me!  Just remember to escape spaces and other special characters with a '\'.  Ex:  `rename "s/some\ test//" *`

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?:

```sh
for i in *_aac.*
do
    mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed -e 's/_aac././'`"
done
```